# ngEnter(ngAnimate) class not getting added in ngDialog

Tags: angularjs

I don't know if there is a bug in ngDialog side or there is something which I am missing but I am not able to see `ngEnter/ngLeave` class getting added.

My `ngDialog` rough Html template :

```
<div class ="Ng-dialogBG"
  ng-swipe-right="swipeRight()"
  ng-swipe-left="swipeLeft()">
<div ng-show="currentID==2" class="canvas-holder" id={{currentID}}>
    <avatarCanvas>
    </avatarcanvas>
 </div>
  <div ng-show="currentID==3" class="canvas-holder" id={{currentID}}>
    <avatarCanvas>
    </avatarcanvas>
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.canvas-holder.ng-enter{
  background-color:blue;
}
.canvas-holder  .ng-leave{
  background-color:black;
}
```

So just for testing I have used a simpler form of the code, and even then I don't see the ngEnter class being added. Swipe action changes the respective `currentID` in the controller to get a particular div.

PS : I have used ngSwipe, ngAnimate in my project, thus the modules have been added properly.
So is it something on the ngDialog part or am I missing someting?

Comment: from where you trying to add class "ng-enter"

Comment: @Sandip There are two div's that are having the class named canvas-holder. So ng-enter will be added as soon as the div is shown.
The logic to show which div is in the controller side and the value is decided by ng-show/ng-if.

Comment: you have to fire event on div show which add required class in that div, in your case it will add "ng-enter" class

Comment: @SandipPatel My div is already having the class `canvas-holder`. What kind of event you talking about to get the ng-enter class?

Comment: It has canvas-holder class but not ng-enter which is your requirement

Comment: @SandipPatel As far as I know, `ngEnter`/`ngLeave` are part of `ngAnimate` and we don't have to define a class named ng-enter. It is usually added with a particular class

Comment: if you want see change add .ng-enter .ng-enter-active

Comment: @ThanhTùng Doesn't work.

Comment: @SandipPatel : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate